# network driver net_device_ops initialisation

Tags: linux

i am not getting how to initialize net_device_ops structure..which is done using ndo_init function, which itself is a member of net_device_ops structure...

> int dev_init(struct net_device *dev)
>
> {
>         ether_setup(dev);
>           struct priv_data *priv;
>           dev -> netdev_ops-> ndo_open            = my_open;
>           dev -> netdev_ops-> ndo_stop            = my_close;
>
> }

can any one help me to do it....i am currently working on linux 3.11.0.12-generic**strong text**